# Floats, Decimals, Prices, and partial quantities

Tags: python, database, django, floating-point, decimal

While the problem in this particular instance deals with Django and Python, I imagine this problem has shown up elsewhere as well.

Float values have a precision problem, and when used for currency can sometimes lead to inaccuracies, so fixed-precision Decimal is the storage type of choice in most instances.

But what about the case where a price is combined with non-integer quantity, such as in an invoice or receipt. Say *Fairy Dust* costs **$19.99 per gram**, and a customer buys **3.5 grams** of the stuff. The price is Decimal, while the quantity is a float.

The total then is `Decimal(19.99) * float(3.5)`. But multiplying floats and Decimals isn't allowed:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> Decimal(19.99) * float(3.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

Of course, we could cast the price to a float first, but then we lose any advantage we otherwise would have gained by storing the value as a decimal. Or we could store the quantity as a decimal, but that would mean arbitrarily picking a range and precision for the quantity. But at design time, the developer wouldn't necessarily *know* what range/precision would be necessary for the quantity (which is why floating point numbers exist). Is there a better way?

I'm sure this problem has been solved before; what is the optimal way to go about this type of calculation?

Comment: You can convert float to decimal like this: `Decimal(str(float(3.5)))`

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `Decimal('19.99')` rather than `Decimal(19.99)`.

Comment: @karthikr I like your answer. I would have voted for it if you had posted it as an answer.

Comment: well.. but you were asking for why not decimal , rather have float. So i wasnt sure. I can still post it as an answer :)

Comment: @grc In real use, the price is actually getting pulled out of the database, not composed on the command line. Also, I wouldn't write `float(3.5)` in real use.

Comment: @karthikr it's a good workaround because the `Decimal` type is arbitrary precision, while decimals in the database are fixed.

Comment: @tylerl Just be careful because `Decimal(19.99)` evaluates to `Decimal('19.9899999...')`. You may have to convert it to a string if you're getting the number as a float.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert float to decimal like this:

```
Decimal(str(float(3.5)))
```

as a workaround.

One more reason to [use float](http://jakeboxer.com/blog/2009/03/17/benchmarking-python-decimal-vs-float/) is this intersting benchmarking article